# Is there a way to download a folder from a branch of a remote git repo in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, repo

I am trying to use a batch script to download a folder that is kept in a branch of a remote repo in Bitbucket. I would like to just download the folder without cloning the entire repo and checking out the branch. It would have to be downloaded from the repo URL. I assume it would have to be downloaded as a .zip or .tar folder then unzipped/untarred. I have been trying to use the git archive command but I have not been able to figure it out. Anyone have some ideas on this?

Comment: [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to use the git client, you could use BitBucket's API [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/downloads/%7Bfilename%7D)
I didn't see an option to download a folder but you could find out which files are inside and download them